# Symfony 4. Workflow initial_place doesn't work

Tags: workflow, symfony4

In workflow.yml I define initial_place.

```
framework:
    workflows:
        case_workflow:
            type: 'workflow' # or 'state_machine'
            audit_trail:
                enabled: true
            marking_store:
                type: 'multiple_state' # or 'single_state'
                arguments:
                    - 'currentPlace'
            supports:
                - App\Entity\Cases\CoreCase

            initial_place: initial

            places:
                - initial
                - review
                - rejected
                - published

            transitions:
                to_review:
                    from: initial
                    to:   review
                publish:
                    from: review
                    to:   published
                reject:
                    from: review
                    to:   rejected
```

In the entity I have defined the property

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
private $currentPlace;
```

In the controller I create the entity and persist it

```
$dieselCase = new DieselCase();
$dieselCase->setUser($account);
$dieselCase->setCustomer($account);
$em->persist($dieselCase);
$em->flush();
```

But currentPlace is not set to initial. Is it a bug in the workflow bundle? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Very Late answer but, **This is how Symfony works**.  `null` == `initial_place`

If you use the `WorkflowInterface` and `getMarking($dieselCase)` when the db is `null` it will report that the place is `['initial']` as you have configured. Or if you use `marking_store: type: 'single_state'` it will report `'initial'`.

The 'currentPlace' marking store will only be populated once you perform a `$workflow->apply($dieselCase, 'to_review')`